# How to return an object from PowerShell to C#

Tags: c#, powershell, virtualization, hyper-v

I'd like to return an object from PowerShell to C#, so C# uses the object inside the C# code to call any method and get a property from the object.

For example, I have a PowerShell script which gets VMs from a host using a Hyper-V module from [pshyperv.codeplex.com](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com). (This GetVM.ps1 is just an example for explanation to return objects).

Once I execute the PowerShell script from Execute(), and then it returns the objects, I want to call any method of the objects from ttt().

1. Does it have possible solution to return objects from PowerShell to C#?
2. Can you correct something wrong in my sample codes if you find (PowerShell, C#)?

## PowerShell

```
Param (
    [String]
    $vmHost = '.',
    [String]
    $vmName
)
Process{
    $private:scriptname = $local:myInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    if  (($vmHost -eq '.' ) -and ($vmName -eq 'ITE'))
    {
        #Write-Output "Executing $private:scriptname on $vmHost"
    }
    try {
        return (Get-VM -Name $vmName -Server $vmHost)
    } catch {Write-Error "Unable to create a VM: $vmName"}
}
```

## C#

```
public void ttt()
{
    ...
    ret = ps.Execute(rs, "GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*' |out-string");

    Trace.WriteLine(ret[0].Name);
}


public object Execute(Runspace runSpace, string command)
{
    bool error = false;
    StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();

    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(command);

    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

    foreach (object item in pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd())
    {
        error = true;
        strOutput.AppendLine(item.ToString());
        retStr.Append(item.ToString());
    }

    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        strOutput.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        retStr.Append(obj.ToString());
    }

    strOutput.Append("\r\n");

    return results;
}
```

## Execution PowerShell Results:

```
PS C:\CVS\IteExtensionCode\Virtualization\VirtualizationTest\Tools\Virtualization\Hyper-V\W2K8> .\GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*'  |gm


   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\virtualization\Msvm_ComputerSystem

Name                          MemberType    Definition
----                          ----------    ----------
VMElementName                 AliasProperty VMElementName = ElementName
RequestStateChange            Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject RequestStateChange(System.UInt16 RequestedState, System.String TimeoutPer...
SetPowerState                 Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject SetPowerState(System.UInt32 PowerState, System.String Time)
AssignedNumaNodeList          Property      System.UInt16[] AssignedNumaNodeList {get;set;}
Caption                       Property      System.String Caption {get;set;}
CreationClassName             Property      System.String CreationClassName {get;set;}
Dedicated                     Property      System.UInt16[] Dedicated {get;set;}
Description                   Property      System.String Description {get;set;}
ElementName                   Property      System.String ElementName {get;set;}
EnabledDefault                Property      System.UInt16 EnabledDefault {get;set;}
EnabledState                  Property      System.UInt16 EnabledState {get;set;}
HealthState                   Property      System.UInt16 HealthState {get;set;}
IdentifyingDescriptions       Property      System.String[] IdentifyingDescriptions {get;set;}
InstallDate                   Property      System.String InstallDate {get;set;}
Name                          Property      System.String Name {get;set;}
NameFormat                    Property      System.String NameFormat {get;set;}
OnTimeInMilliseconds          Property      System.UInt64 OnTimeInMilliseconds {get;set;}
OperationalStatus             Property      System.UInt16[] OperationalStatus {get;set;}
OtherDedicatedDescriptions    Property      System.String[] OtherDedicatedDescriptions {get;set;}
OtherEnabledState             Property      System.String OtherEnabledState {get;set;}
OtherIdentifyingInfo          Property      System.String[] OtherIdentifyingInfo {get;set;}
PowerManagementCapabilities   Property      System.UInt16[] PowerManagementCapabilities {get;set;}
PrimaryOwnerContact           Property      System.String PrimaryOwnerContact {get;set;}
PrimaryOwnerName              Property      System.String PrimaryOwnerName {get;set;}
ProcessID                     Property      System.UInt32 ProcessID {get;set;}
RequestedState                Property      System.UInt16 RequestedState {get;set;}
ResetCapability               Property      System.UInt16 ResetCapability {get;set;}
Roles                         Property      System.String[] Roles {get;set;}
Status                        Property      System.String Status {get;set;}
StatusDescriptions            Property      System.String[] StatusDescriptions {get;set;}
TimeOfLastConfigurationChange Property      System.String TimeOfLastConfigurationChange {get;set;}
TimeOfLastStateChange         Property      System.String TimeOfLastStateChange {get;set;}
__CLASS                       Property      System.String __CLASS {get;set;}
__DERIVATION                  Property      System.String[] __DERIVATION {get;set;}
__DYNASTY                     Property      System.String __DYNASTY {get;set;}
__GENUS                       Property      System.Int32 __GENUS {get;set;}
__NAMESPACE                   Property      System.String __NAMESPACE {get;set;}
__PATH                        Property      System.String __PATH {get;set;}
__PROPERTY_COUNT              Property      System.Int32 __PROPERTY_COUNT {get;set;}
__RELPATH                     Property      System.String __RELPATH {get;set;}
__SERVER                      Property      System.String __SERVER {get;set;}
__SUPERCLASS                  Property      System.String __SUPERCLASS {get;set;}
ConvertFromDateTime           ScriptMethod  System.Object ConvertFromDateTime();
ConvertToDateTime             ScriptMethod  System.Object ConvertToDateTime();


PS C:\CVS\IteExtensionCode\Virtualization\VirtualizationTest\Tools\Virtualization\Hyper-V\W2K8> .\GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*'

Host                      VMElementName             State        Up-Time (mS) Owner
--------                  -------------             -----        ------------ -----
T06CORE                   ITE                       Stopped      0
T06CORE                   ITE2                      Stopped      0
```

Comment: "Can you correct something wrong": please tell us what is wrong: does it fail to compile? Does it give an error at runtime? Don't make use guess.

Comment: I don't get the right return value. I want to know how to return objects from powershell to c#? I want to return the objects of 'get-vm' but c# doesn't seem to get the result. :-(

Comment: Please tell us what `pipeline.Invoke`'s return contains? (In other words show your working so far: where in debugging this have you got stuck?)

Comment: I got the screenshot. <iframe src="https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=E5BCF1468DF890B3&resid=E5BCF1468DF890B3%21251&authkey=ANEDC-nl1vbBigU" width="320" height="34" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: another high resolution one. <iframe src="https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=E5BCF1468DF890B3&resid=E5BCF1468DF890B3%21252&authkey=ACtRwEC7rioZBR8" width="320" height="34" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: It looks return the text string of powershell execution of "GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*'" not the objects.

Comment: I think I found the reason why it didn't return the objects. In the C# code, ret = ps.Execute(rs, "GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*' |out-string"); will return only string because of 'out-string'. when I removed this, it returns objects correctly. Thank you.

Comment: 1. The use of a slide show in Sky Drive doesn't make this viewable: what's wrong with a PNG? 2. See the answer I'm about to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've got a [`PSObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28VS.85%29.aspx) wrapping a string: which looks correct (given the `out-string` you are using). You need to extract the string from the `PSObject` with its `BaseObject5` property.

If you are expecting a collection of the objects that `Get-VM` returns then don't use `Out-String`.

Comment: In the meantime, do you have any idea how to use the objects? I got the objects but can't call a method or get a property from one of objects. for example, can't get a Name from VM objects.

Comment: ret = ps.Execute(rs, "GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*'");
Collection<PSObject> results = (Collection<PSObject>)ret;                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
   How to call obj's any method? Debugging doesn't show any method, but properties like 'BaseObject', 'ImmediateBaseObject', etc. It's not like the result of .\GetVM.ps1 -vmName 'ITE*'  |gm
   
}

Comment: It shows 'BaseObject', 'ImmediateBaseObject', 'Members', 'Methods', 'Properties', 'TypeNames'. Is there an way to extract the methods also?

Comment: @spark You need to read up on PowerShell's "Extended Type System" (it is too much for a [SO] answer). The page MSDN used to have seems to have gone but plenmty of hits on search engines.